# Rust bindgen use of pointer addresse `*mut i8` for allocating memory for camera, getting "cannot be sent between threads safely"

Tags: rust, void-pointers, ids, rust-bindgen, ueye

#### **tl&dr**:  How to work with `*mut i8` so it is thread safe for use in `lazy_static!` Mutex ?

I have a function that generates a pointer address in the form of `*mut i8`, which I want to store in a `struct` that is initiated by

```rust
lazy_static! {static ref HARDWARE: Mutex<HardwareT> = Mutex::new(HardwareT::new());}
```

I get

```rust
error[E0277]: `*mut i8` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src\lib.rs:21:1
   |
21 | / lazy_static! {
22 | |     static ref HARDWARE: Mutex<HardwareT> = Mutex::new(HardwareT::new());
23 | | }
   | |_^ `*mut i8` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut i8`
   = note: required for `Unique<*mut i8>` to implement `Send`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<*mut i8>`
```

#### Complete story

I'm using rust bindgen to control a ueye camera.

The way it takes a picture, is it allocates a given amount of memory and the user has to pass the pointer address between functions (I guess something Rust is not very happy with).
To describe my question, I'll use the python code and then show where I'm having issues. (without the actual hardware, it is difficult to make a MVE).

python example code: https://fr.ids-imaging.com/programming-examples-details/simple-live-image-acquisition-with-the-python-interface-pyueye.html

```py
# SimpleLive_Pyueye_OpenCV.py
# In the python example, we first generate a pointer address that we keep in a variable
pcImageMemory = ueye.c_mem_p()
...

# Then we allocate the memory through the C api 
err = ueye.is_AllocImageMem(..some args..,  pcImageMemory, ..more args..)
check(err)
...

#Later on, we call this memory address to get the array
array = ueye.get_data(pcImageMemory, ..more args..)
```

Here is the original C definition from the documentation.

```
INT is_AllocImageMem (..some args.., char** ppcMem, ..more args..)
```

Now, in rust, the generated function to allocate the memory is

```rust
// bindings.rs generated code 
extern "C" {
    pub fn is_AllocImageMem(
        ..some args..,
        ppcMem: *mut *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char,
        ..more args..
    ) -> INT;
}
```

I thus need a `*mut *mut i8`, which I managed to get working with this code,

```rust
pub fn allocate_img_memory(..some args..) -> Result<*mut i8, MessageError> {
    let mut pc_image_memory =  Box::into_raw(Box::new(0i8)) as *mut i8;
    let err = unsafe { 
        ueye::is_AllocImageMem(
             ..some args.., 
             &mut  pc_image_memory as *mut  *mut i8, 
             ..more args..
        ) };
   
    check(err)?;
    Ok(pc_image_memory))
}
```

This system works in terms of generating the pointer address which i can use, however, this function is `impl` in a `struct HardwareT` that is initiated in `lazy_static!` Mutex

```rust
lazy_static! {static ref HARDWARE: Mutex<HardwareT> = Mutex::new(HardwareT::new());}
```

therefore I get the error message about thread safety.

##### **Question**: How to convert `pc_image_memory` so as to keep the thread safety and store it in my struct?

---

Edit 1 :
here how the hardware struct is defined in this example

```rust
pub struct HardwareT{
    image_memory: *mut i8,
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: if `Mutex` is `std::sync::Mutex`, its `new()` is const fn new, you don't need `lazy_static`.

Comment: Please provide the definition of `HardwareT` as part of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)